# What part of the grid tag is wrong?

Tags: html, css

```
.home__container{
  gap: 1rem;
}

.home__content{
  grid-template-columns: .5fr 3fr;
  padding-top: 3.5rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.home__social{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: max-content;
  row-gap: 1rem;
}

.home__social-icon{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.home__social-icon:hover{
  color: var(--first-color-alt);
}

.home__blob{
  width: 200px;
  fill: var(--first-color)
}

.home__blob-img{
  width: 170px;
}
.home__data{
  grid-column: 1/3;
}

.home__title{
  font-size: var(--big-font-size);
}

.home__subtitle{
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  color: var(--text-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.home__description{
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-2);
}

.home__scroll{
  /* display: none; */
}

.home__scroll-button{
  color: var(--first-color);
  transition: .3s;
}

.home__scroll-button:hover{
  transform: translateY(.25rem);
}

.home__scroll-mouse{
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.home__scroll-name{
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  margin-right: var(--mb-0-25);
}

.home__scroll-arrow{
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

.about__container {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.about__img {
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: .5rem;
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.about__description {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: var(--md-2-5);
}

.about__info {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin-bottom: var(--md-2-5);
}

.about__info-title {
  font-size: var(--h2-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
  color: var(--title-color);
}

.about__info-title,
.about__info-name {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.about__buttons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


                        <div class="home__data">
                        <h1 class="home__title">I'am mijoung</h1>
                        <h3 class="home__subtitle">Frontend developer</h3>
                        <p class="home__description">High level experience in web design and 
                            development knowledge, 
                            producing quality work.</p>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#contact" class="button button--fiex">
                                Contact Me <i class="uil uil-message button__icon"></i>
                            </a>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="home__scroll">
                            <a href="#about" class="home__scroll-button button--flex">
                                <i class="uil uil-mouse-alt home__scroll-mouse"></i>
                                <span class="home__scroll-name">Scroll down</span>
                                <i class="uil uil-arrow-down home__scroll-arrow"></i>
                </div>
            </section>

            <!--==================== ABOUT ====================-->
            
            <section class="about section" id="about">
                <h2 class="section__title">About Me</h2>
                <span class="section__subtitle">My introduction</span>

                
                <div class="about__container container grid">
                    <img src="assets\img\mi.png" alt="" class="about__img">

                    <div class="about__data">
                        <p class="about__description">Web developer, with extensive knowledge and years of 
                            experience, working in web technologies and Ui / Ux design, delivering quality work.</p>
                    
                            <div class="about__info">
                        <div>
                            <span class="about__info-title">08+</span>
                            <span class="about__info-name">Years <br> experience</span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                            <span class="about__info-title">20+</span>
                            <span class="about__info-name">Completed <br> project</span>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                            <span class="about__info-title">05+</span>
                            <span class="about__info-name">Companies <br> worked </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="about__buttons">
                    <a download="" href="assets/pdf/Alexa-Cv.pdf" class="button button--flex">
                    Download CV<i class="uil uil-download-alt button__icon"></i></a>
                </div>        
                </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

The grid of the tag outputs the home__scroll  style

If you declare it home__scroll

Home__scroll  style not output only when declared grid to output home__scroll  style

Wondering where the code is weirdly twisted

When declaring an  tag, the  tag will not be output, possibly due to the influence of the grid tag, and the style tag that is superimposed on the grid tag will be output

Comment: I don’t claim to understand the question fully, could you try to explain the problem more. Putting the code as a runnable snippet might help us, as would pictures of what is happening and what is wanted.

Comment: I can’t see home__container or content in your html, and anyway things like gap property are not inherited. Make a minimal example, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I've already solved all the issues related to that matter. I would like to express my sincere gratitude to you for your dedication.